# Resgatar dados de outro componente angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directives

Tenho um componente chamado login que quando realiza o login preenche os dados do objeto usuário, eu preciso pegar o campo "cargo" deste objeto e receber em outro componente.

Eu tentei:

**login.component.ts:**

```
 public usuario: Usuario = new Usuario()

fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): void{
 //função que faz o login...
 this.enviaCargo(this.usuario.cargo)
}

  enviaCargo(cargo: string): void{ //aqui eu envio o valor para uma função do serviço.
    this.authService.setCargo(cargo);
  }
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
 public cargo: string;

  setCargo(cargo: string){
    this.cargo = cargo;
  }

  getCargo(){
    return this.cargo;
  }
```

**E então, no componente que quero este dado, eu faço:**

```
private cargo: string;

  ngOnInit() {

    if (typeof this.cargo === 'undefined' || !this.cargo) { 
      this.cargo = this.loginService.getCargo();
    } 
 }
```

Quando logo o componente recebe o cargo, porém quando recarrego a página, eu perco este dado, porque ele só é preenchido quando faz o login.

Comment: Porque recarrega a página?

Comment: Porque minha ideia é usar o cargo como property binding, se o cargo for diferente de 'a', aplica o disabled. quando faço o login o elemento fica desabilitado, mas se eu recarregar a página, o cargo se torna undefined

Comment: Você pode salvar em um localStorage se for o caso.

`localStorage.setItem("cargo",  this.loginService.getCargo()): `

Ao fazer logout remove esse cara

Comment: eu não queria fazer com localstorage porque esse dado pode mudar em tempo real, não me parece ser a melhor alternativa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que setar no localStorage seja a melhor opção, porem se quiser algo diferente, tente utilizando o Event Emitter do angular. Ex:

**emitter.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EmitterService {

    static cargoEmitter= new EventEmitter();

}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { EmitterService } from './emitter.service';

public usuario: Usuario = new Usuario()

fazerLogin(email: string, password: string): void{
 //função que faz o login...
 this.enviaCargo(this.usuario.cargo)
}

  enviaCargo(cargo: string): void{ //aqui eu envio o valor para uma função do serviço.
    this.authService.setCargo(cargo);
    EmitterService.cargoEmitter.emit({ cargo: cargo });
  }
```

**componente que recebe o dado**

```
import { EmitterService } from './emitter.service';
private cargo: string;

  ngOnInit() {

   EmitterService.cargoEmitter.subscribe(data => { 
      if(data){
        this.cargo = data;
      }
    });
 }
```